# What are the pros and cons to use non-parametric methods to estimate probabilities?

Tags: regression, logistic, large-data, splines

When we have large amount of data, using logistic regression may suffer from high bias, i.e., linear model can underfit/too simple for large amount of data.

I am thinking to use some non-parametric methods to estimate the probability. For example, I am building a toy model from `diamond` data. (see attached code for details) the figure 1 the logistic regression model, and figure 2 is using splines to estimate the probability.

The idea is using the nonlinear and non-parametric way, we can see more details on how probability change respect independent variable.

Is this approach valid? What are the pros and cons?

[image]

---

Here are details for the model

```
# making toy data
library(ggplot2)
d=subset(diamonds, carat<1.3 & carat > 0.3)
d$is_expensive=ifelse(d$price>2500,1,0)

# logistic regression
p=ggplot(d, aes(carat, is_expensive))+geom_jitter(height = 0.05)
p=p+geom_smooth(method='glm', se=F, method.args = list(family = "binomial"))
p=p+theme_gray(15)
p

# spline
p=ggplot(d, aes(carat, is_expensive))+geom_jitter(height = 0.05)
p=p+geom_smooth(method='gam', se=F, formula = y ~ s(x,k=25))+theme_gray(15)
p
```

---

Thanks for the comments. I am making a toy example on `diamond` data. What I want to ask is for some general data set, if we have one continuous variable as independent variable and one binary variable as response variable.

Comment: (1) What is the source of this "high bias" to which you refer?  (2) Are you asking about models that might overfit the data, such as a spline with 25 knots, or about validated or cross-validated models? (3) How do you envision people exploiting tiny differences in estimated probabilities like those in your illustration? (4) Are you referring to "data" as just a batch of numbers (which is what the undocumented `diamonds` dataset is) or are you considering them to be random (or somehow representative) samples of something? (BTW, `is_cheap` has been misnamed!)

Comment: For starters, that model isn't all that detailed.  You're not telling ggplot to fit a binomial model, and I don't know if Hadley has done it for you or not.  Second, when running your code, I can't specify that automatic smoothness selection be done with REML, which it should.  If you don't know what either of these things are, then you might consider asking a more basic question, or learning a bit more about the methods that you are using.

Comment: @whuber OP means bias in the ML sense, which is that the difference between $f(x)$ and $E[\hat{f}(x)]$ is large.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the questions that helped me to clear my question and correct the misnamed column.

Comment: @generic Thank you for those clarifications.  Absent a probability model--which in the example would seem to require some information about how the data were collected or perhaps some kind of randomized internal cross-validation scheme--I cannot see how "$E$" could have any meaning.

Comment: First, arbitrarily partitioning continuously distributed information into binary data is almost never a good idea, see, e.g., Harrell's comments on *Dichotomania* in his blog post, http://www.fharrell.com/2017/04/statistical-errors-in-medical-literature.html#catg. Next, while I've read that LR can be biased in the case of rare or extreme events due to the fact that it's tails are symmetric and finite, I've never read that LR is biased as a function of sample size -- unless you are referring to modelling rare events data.

Comment: thanks @DJohnson I was trying to make an example data. But still appreciate the link you provided, I never know this in detail.